# best method of drawing a bezier line

Tags: javascript, flash, html, canvas, svg

I have a conundrum with a design.

Imagine the new Facebook timeline with lots of chronological posts attached to it. However instead of a straight line I need to make a *randomized* curved line with the content placed against it like so:
[image]

The complexity comes in because as the user scrolls more posts are loaded (facebook/google images style) so the line could almost be endless.

As far as I can tell my options are:

1. SVG - poor support in old browsers
2. Flash layer - embed wil be huge and cause performance issues
3. canvas - again the canvas will be huge and might cause performance issues

**QUESTION**

Are there any cross browser gfx libraries which could do this, preferably with support for IE7/8? Or is there a smarter way to do this which I might be overlooking?

**EDIT:ANSWER**
See below, Raphael proved to be the best way I found to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SVG via [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) - it supports IE6+.

Answer (score 1):

Also investigate Catmull Rom Curves

http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?v=2&q=catmullromspline

Answer (score 0):

If the placement is predictable and static you could get away with using prerendered curve segments as regular backgrounds. It'll work on everything and it will be very easy to implement.

Should you want to get fancy you could store the needed translation per curve segment and randomly pick ones that will keep you inside your set width.